# Convert GPS coordinates from rational fractions to degrees

Tags: python, gps, exif

I'm trying to make sense of the GPS coordinates returned from the EXIF tags in my images:

## my accessor for the coordinates

```
@property
def GPSCoordinatesRat(self):
coords = (str(self._EXIF_GPSLatitude) +
          str(self._EXIF_GPSLongitude_Ref) +
          str(self._EXIF_GPSLongitude)) +
          str(self._EXIF_GPSLongitude_Ref)
```

## example

```
>>> s.GPSCoordinatesRat
'[Fraction(40, 1), Fraction(3901, 100), Fraction(0, 1)]W[Fraction(73, 1), Fraction(4691, 100), Fraction(0, 1)]W'
```

How can I make this read something like:

```
35° 42' 1" N, 71° 37' 0" W
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you converting everything to strings?

Comment: Otherwise I get a TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: So doing it wronger is supposed to make doing it wrong right? o_O

Comment: Something smells wrong with this code. What exactely do you plan to DO with the output of this? Printing human readable? Entry for another operation? Calculations?

Comment: Do you already know how to convert from decimal coordinates to hours and minutes?

Comment: Suggestion: when giving examples, at least try to make the output values based on the input, not some unrelated random numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Look here to convert the float to degrees, minutes, and seconds: http://geography.about.com/library/howto/htdegrees.htm

What's not mentioned there: If the location is on the western hemisphere the sign is negative, i.e. multiply the (integer) degrees by -1. Same for locations on the southern hemisphere.

Answer (score 0):

Passing each `Fraction` to the `float` constructor will turn it into a floating point number.

```
>>> float(fractions.Fraction(3901, 100))
39.01
```